Repartitioning a spark dataframe by column name(s)
I'm trying to understand repartion() function of the Spark dataframe.
data = [("aaa", "apples", 3000),
    ("bbb", "apples", 4600),
    ("ccc", "apples", 4100),
    ("ddd", "orange", 3000),
    ("aaa", "amla", 3500),
    ("azw", "orange", 3300),
    ("yux", "orange", 3900),
    ("freq", "amla", 3000),
    ("upa", "amla", 2000),
    ("vashat", "apples", 4100)

columns = ["location","name","price"]

df_fruits = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)
df_fruits.show()

When i executed the below line
df_fruits_prt_bynumber = df_fruits.repartition(5)
print(df_fruits_prt_bynumber.rdd.getNumPartitions()) # returns 5

It returned the number of partitions as 5
But, when I repartitioned using column name should the partition count be 3 or 1?  The below line returned count as 1
df_fruits_prt_bycols = df_fruits.repartition("name")
print(df_fruits_prt_bycols.rdd.getNumPartitions()) # returns 1

Spark official page at the below url
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html][1]
states the below
cols:str or Column partitioning columns. Changed in version 1.6: Added optional arguments to specify the partitioning columns. Also made numPartitions optional if partitioning columns are specified.
If repartitioning by column will not partition a dataframe by the distinct count of values of the given column(s) (data above it is 3 distinct fruits) what is the purpose of partitioning by column ?  Or am i missing/misunderstood any  meticulous concept by the creators of spark?  Clarifying on this will be an eye-opener.
